# How to get a domain name from the url using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a domain name like **'https://abc.example.com/pqr/controllername/actionname/id'** so I want only **'https://abc.example.com/pqr/'** from above url by using a JavaScript how do i get it?

i have try - 1) window.location.origin 2) window.location.host- it will return only **https://abc.example.com**

Comment: In the example above, the domain name is `abc.co.in` not `abc.co.in/pqr`

Comment: Please refer to this doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL  so we are aligned on the terms to use, in particular: _URL_ versus _domain_

Comment: (I edited your link so that it doesn't point to an an actual site that is irrelevant for the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)-API

```js
let x = new URL("https://somefakedomain.abcd.com/pqr/controllername/actionname/id");
// take your pick
console.log(`${x.origin}/${x.pathname.split("/")[1]}/`);
console.log(`${x.origin}/${x.pathname.slice(1).split("/")[0]}/`);
console.log(`${x.toString().substr(0, x.toString().indexOf("pqr") + 4)}`);
console.log(`${x.origin}/${x.pathname.substr(x.pathname.indexOf("pqr"), 4)}`);
```